# Capacitive load of connecting cable for a temperature sensor

Tags: wire, capacitive

An LM35 temperature sensor is 4m removed from the Arduino to connect it too. The available cable has 4 wires with a diameter of 0.6mm (0.28 mm<sup>2</sup> area) as well as a, seemingly aluminum, shield . The sensor's [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/LM35) says on page 14 that the LM35 can drive 50pF capacitive load.

I have a general understanding of a capacitor from physics courses. But for the signalling wire of the sensor, what would be the 2nd "plate" of the capacitor or, more specifically, how would I estimate the capacitive load of the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the data sheet makes recommendations for driving capacitive loads such as these: -

[image]

> *But for the signalling wire of the sensor, what would be the 2nd
> "plate" of the capacitor or, more specifically, how would I estimate
> the capacitive load of the setup?*

You can fairly well assume that the capacitive load will be about 100 pF per metre of cable. This will be seen between the send wire and the screen or ground return. This would be typically a cable of transmission impedance around 50 Ω and, for the sake of trying to figure out what the actual capacitance might be, you might as well just implement solution A or solution B as outlined in the DS extract above.

Solution A is simplest but it requires that the termination impedance of the receiving circuit is much, much bigger than 2k so you don't create a significant voltage divider error. Or, use solution B (a little more complex but not much more).

Answer (score 1):

STP wire is about 60 to 80 pF/m, coax is about 90 pF/m, so if you follow Fig 12 and add 3k in series this will prevent oscillation of the 1uA current limited emitter follower use for internal negative feedback.  The additional snubber in Fig 13 is if you happen to use very rapid step changes or want to suppress impulse or line large current noise coupling into the 3k output impedance created.

Answer (score 0):

If you only look at one wire in the cable, it will run inside the cable next to other wires and the shield. It will have capacitance to all neighbouring 3 wires and the shield that surrounds it.

To estimate the cable capacitance, generally cables meant for data transmission state the cable capacitance in the data sheet.